# Подскажите API с логотипами или ключевыми цветами сайтов

Tags: javascript, api, дизайн, сервисы, дизайн-api

Где можно достать ключевые цвета сайтов или их логотипы? Есть подобные сервисы или самому писать?

Суть API представляю себе так: я даю ссылку на сайт, а получаю цвет сайта вычисленный по первому непрозрачному пикселю иконки (и, если необходимо, затемненному/осветленному на несколько тонов) и если это возможно - его логотип.

Сам вычислять цвет по иконке не могу (из-за ограничений cross-origin в JS), а логотипы собирать - задача для роботов

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сервис http://favicongrabber.com/service-api-reference, у него есть API, который поддерживает в том числе клиентские запросы. Сервис возвращает favicon для сайта, например:

```
fetch('http://favicongrabber.com/api/grab/github.com')
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        document.querySelector('#w').innerHTML = '<img src="' + data.icons[0].src + '" />';
    });
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/maximzasorin/tk9dk4Lr/

Comment: О, спасибо, отличный сервис для поиска иконок сайтов. Как раз искал недавно такой. Но это не совсем то, о чем я спросил. Попробуйте конвертировать иконку в канвас и узнать цвет пикселя - на втором этапе получите исключение о кросс-доменном запросе. Это значит, что вы не можете сами изучить иконку, что бы узнать её цвет (что по логике безопасности абсолютно правильно, иначе можно было бы незаметно воровать ваши личные фотографии с разных сайтов). А значит, нужен сервис, который занимался бы этим вместо вас и отдавал бы только результат, в виде "ключевого цвета" сайта

Comment: @TryCatch посмотрите репозиторий: https://github.com/keeweb/favicon-proxy, там есть ссылка на работающий сервис, кстати favicon можно еще брать с favicon.yandex.net, он поддерживает CORS: https://favicon.yandex.net/favicon/google.com

Comment: Гуглояндексы отдают неправильные иконки. Для теста качества можно проверять gmail.com